# DirectX/с++ и PhysX

Tags: c++, directx

Можно ли в своем проекте сделать так чтоб DirectX все просчитывал и прорисовывал объекты, а  физику рассчитывал PhysX? Если да, то где можно найти сэмпл-примеры?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

семплы поищи в PhysX SDK. Там много интересного и использует он DirectX для прорисовки. Только там достаточно сложно и много кода, а так то, что надо!

Comment: Да вообще куууча кода. Не понимаю зачем?? Если семплы юзают новички, то можно и было сделать по проще. =)